# Matlab Camera Calibration Toolbox Principal Point Pixel Indexing

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I want to use the [Matlab Camera Calibrator app](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameracalibrator-app.html), but I can't find out if the principal point, i.e. `c_x` and `c_y` of the camera intrinsics (see [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameraparameters-class.html)), use the standard Matlab index starting from 1 (see [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html)) or an index starting from 0, as e.g. in OpenCV. Does anybody know?

Comment: General comment. Thread very very carefully if your application depends critically on the precise location of the principal point (btw, you erroneously called it the optical center in your original posting). It is very difficult to calibrate it with any accuracy, since the calibration error is quite insensitive to its location unless the calibration procedure is specifically designed for it.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the standard MATLAB index starting from 1. [More information](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/coordinate-systems.html) on coordinate systems used in camera calibration and 3-D reconstruction.

Comment: So the optical center is represented by its absolute position in image coordinates rather than an offset from the image borders. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @baumlin, I am not sure I understand what you mean. The optical center is in the pixel coordinates, where the center of the upper-left pixel is (1,1).

Comment: What I meant by offset is the distance of the optical center from the image origin. So if for example the optical center would be described as an offset of (320,240), then the optical center would actually be at (321,241) in matlab image coordinates. Since I am used to OpenCV (with 0 index), I somehow never thought about whether the optical center is expressed by an absolute position or an offset from the image origin.

Comment: @baumlin, to me it seems easier to define an image coordinate system, and think of the  optical center as a point in those coordinates. In the MATLAB's image coordinates, the top-left pixel's center is (1,1). In OpenCV's image coordinates it is  (0,0). So if you want to move from one system into the other you need to subtract 1 from the optical center.